# while using d3js my json file didn't read got error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/tree.json`. Cross         origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: `http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource`.

my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            text {
                font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            .name {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .about {
                fill: #777;
                font-size: smaller;
            }
            .link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #000;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var margin = {
                top: 0,
                right: 320,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0
            },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .separation(function(a, b) {
                return a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : .5;
            })
                .children(function(d) {
                return d.parents;
            })
                .size([height, width]);

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            d3.json(" tree.json", function(error, json) {
                if (error) throw error;

                var nodes = tree.nodes(json);

                var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                    .data(tree.links(nodes))
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", elbow);

                var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                })

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "name")
                    .attr("x", 8)
                    .attr("y", -6)
                    .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 8)
                    .attr("y", 8)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .attr("class", "about lifespan")
                    .text(function(d) {
                    return d.born + "–" + d.died;
                });

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 8)
                    .attr("y", 8)
                    .attr("dy", "1.86em")
                    .attr("class", "about location")
                    .text(function(d) {
                    return d.location;
                });
            });

            function elbow(d, i) {
                return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x + "H" + d.target.y + "V" + d.target.x + (d.target.children ? "" : "h" + margin.right);
            }
        </script>
```

and `json`

```
{
    "name": "Clifford Shanks",
    "born": 1862,
    "died": 1906,
    "location": "Petersburg, VA",
    "parents": [{
        "name": "James Shanks",
        "born": 1831,
        "died": 1884,
        "location": "Petersburg, VA",
        "parents": [{
            "name": "Robert Shanks",
            "born": 1781,
            "died": 1871,
            "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
        }, {
            "name": "Elizabeth Shanks",
            "born": 1795,
            "died": 1871,
            "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Ann Emily Brown",
        "born": 1826,
        "died": 1866,
        "location": "Brunswick/Petersburg, VA",
        "parents": [{
            "name": "Henry Brown",
            "born": 1792,
            "died": 1845,
            "location": "Montgomery, NC"
        }, {
            "name": "Sarah Houchins",
            "born": 1793,
            "died": 1882,
            "location": "Montgomery, NC"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have  `d3.json( " tree.json", function(error, json)` which use HTTP GET method. 
This error is because you are just opening html documents directly from the browser you need a HTTP Web Server to serve your json file

to run without server by avoid Get Request

```js
var json  = {
    "name": "Clifford Shanks",
    "born": 1862,
    "died": 1906,
    "location": "Petersburg, VA",
    "parents": [{
        "name": "James Shanks",
        "born": 1831,
        "died": 1884,
        "location": "Petersburg, VA",
        "parents": [{
            "name": "Robert Shanks",
            "born": 1781,
            "died": 1871,
            "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
        }, {
            "name": "Elizabeth Shanks",
            "born": 1795,
            "died": 1871,
            "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Ann Emily Brown",
        "born": 1826,
        "died": 1866,
        "location": "Brunswick/Petersburg, VA",
        "parents": [{
            "name": "Henry Brown",
            "born": 1792,
            "died": 1845,
            "location": "Montgomery, NC"
        }, {
            "name": "Sarah Houchins",
            "born": 1793,
            "died": 1882,
            "location": "Montgomery, NC"
        }]
    }]
}

var margin = {
                top: 0,
                right: 320,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0
            },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .separation(function(a, b) {
                return a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : .5;
            })
                .children(function(d) {
                return d.parents;
            })
                .size([height, width]);

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

     
                var nodes = tree.nodes(json);

                var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                    .data(tree.links(nodes))
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", elbow);

                var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                })

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "name")
                    .attr("x", 8)
                    .attr("y", -6)
                    .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 8)
                    .attr("y", 8)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .attr("class", "about lifespan")
                    .text(function(d) {
                    return d.born + "–" + d.died;
                });

                node.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 8)
                    .attr("y", 8)
                    .attr("dy", "1.86em")
                    .attr("class", "about location")
                    .text(function(d) {
                    return d.location;
                });
           ;

            function elbow(d, i) {
                return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x + "H" + d.target.y + "V" + d.target.x + (d.target.children ? "" : "h" + margin.right);
            }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```